# Export XML on azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am new to azure so hope my question is clear, In azure data factory I am trying to run a query and export the result as XML to my blob storage, but 'copy data' feature nor 'data flow' features allow me to do so, for JSON they work perfectly.

Does anyone knows how to generate xml files from azure data factory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data factory supports XML formats with dataset but unfortunately we cannot use XML datasets a sinks. I recently had to export SQL query result into Azure Data Lake Storage as XML files. I had to jump through couple of hoops to get it working. I happened to write a blog explaining the whole setup here, https://blogs.dhrutara.com/blogs/data_factory_sql_server_table_export_xml

Please let me know if you have any questions.